# Display title from database based on category dropdown AJAX

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, codeigniter

I have a table that looks like:

```
id | page_name | category 
--------------------------
1  | Tornado   | Air     
2  | Car       | Vehicles
```

Dropdown for example (HTML):

```
<select id="dropdown_categories">
  <option value="Air">Air</option>
  <option value="Vehicles">Vehicles</option>
</select>
```

I want that when i select Air i will see only result 1 (Tornado).
Tried something like that:

controller:

```
    public function Get_Page_By_Category ( $category ) {
    $data['pages_cat'] = $this->page_model->get_page_by_category($category);
}
```

model:

```
     function get_page_by_category ( $category ) {

     $this->db->select('*')->from('page')->where('page.category =', $category);
     $result = $this->db->get();

     return $result;
 }
```

ajax:

```
<script type="application/javascript">

$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#dropdown_categories").change(function(){
        alert($('#dropdown_categories option:selected').val());
    })
});
</script>
```

Not sure how to continue, what is the best approach to this?

Answer (score 1):

You should use ajax for this. try like this.

```
  $(document).ready(function() {
    $("#dropdown_categories").change(function(){
       var val = $('#dropdown_categories option:selected').val();    
        $.ajax({
            url: "path to controller function/value of select box present in var val",
            type: "POST",
            dataType: "HTML",
            async: false,
            success: function(data) {
                  alert(data)                  
      }
  }); 

 });
});
```

in controller you can echo the value, that will come in success of ajax in data variable, i have alerted there, you can use how even you want

Comment: I think there is some problem with controller or model.. if i go to the url get_page_by_category?category=Air i have Error Number: 1064

You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '' at line 3

SELECT * FROM (`page`) WHERE `page`.`category` =

Filename: /var/www/html/models/page_model.php

Line Number: 97

Comment: are you using get?? or its a function parameter??

Comment: i have given there for function parameter, so it should be get_page_by_category/Air

Answer (score 0):

You are using jQuery, so you can use the jQuery ajax. It's easy. You can use:

```
var val = $('#dropdown_categories option:selected').val();
$.ajax({
  url: "url",
  type: "POST",
  dataType: "application/json,"
  data: {value: val, callback: php_function_to_call, args: [array_of_arguments_of_php_function]}
  success: function(data){
    document.title = data.title;
  }
})
```

Now the php:

```
function myFunction($arguments_if_you_have){
    //get the databse result here;
    //notice: ajax only returns data, when there is something sent to the output stream, so we must use echo
    echo json_encode($result);
}
if(isset($_POST['callback'])){

    if(isset($_POST['args'])){
        call_user_func_array($_POST['callback'], $_POST['args']);
    }
    call_user_func_array($_POST['callback'], array());

}
```